# Select single row for column value

Tags: java, database, jpa

Here is sample table data which is dynamic.

```
ColId     Name      JobId    Instance

1       aaaaaaaaa   1       2dc757b
2       bbbbbbbbb   1       2dc757b
3       aaaaaaaaa   1       010dbb8
4       bbbbbbbbb   1       010dbb8
5       bbbbbbbbb   1       faa2733
6       aaaaaaaaa   1       faa2733
7       aaaaaaaaa   1       bc13d69
8       aaaaaaaaa   1       9428f4d
```

I want output like

```
ColId      Name     JobId   Instance

1       aaaaaaaaa   1       2dc757b
3       aaaaaaaaa   1       010dbb8
5       bbbbbbbbb   1       faa2733
7       aaaaaaaaa   1       bc13d69
8       aaaaaaaaa   1       9428f4d
```

What should be the JPA query so that I can retrieve entire row having only single 'Instance'(there is no max min condition involved). 
I need one row for each 'Instance' value

Comment: Try this query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b05dfd/2 don't know how you will implement in JPA.. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`FROM table t GROUP BY t.instance` should suit your needs.

Comment: @anotherNovice1984 Are you sure this isn't what you're looking for? It won't list all rows: there'll be only one row per `instance`. See how behaves this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7d1f/1/0) (it's MySQL but I guess JPA must have implemented it the same way).

Comment: Not sure if it's problem with Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 (version I'm using). Hope you know it doesn't allow commands like "SELECT * FROM `my_table` GROUP BY `last_name`;" Instead of "select * " it expects column names and all the columns mentioned are expected to be in GROUP BY clause. I tried having all columns mentioned explicitly, it  returns all rows @sp00m

Comment: @anotherNovice1984 I think you can also omit the `SELECT ...` part by simply using `FROM table t GROUP BY t.instance` (as I put in my answer - it was'nt an oversight `:)`). At least `HQL` allows it.

Comment: @anotherNovice1984: I think this should work but the issue is that you are possibly using `creatQuery("select...")` or `createNameQuery("select....")` try Using `createNativeQuery("select...")`

Comment: SQL should not allow returning column values that aren't in the group by, as it doesn't know which of the different possible values to pick.  A native query will only help if using the row num and prev value db specific SQL solution shown in a comment by Meherzad

Answer (score 0):

Something like JPQL "Select entity from Entity entity where entity.id in (select min(subinstance.id) from Entity subinstance group by subinstance.instance)"

Functions like count, min, avg etc are allowed over columns not included in the group by statement, so any such should work if it returns a single id value from the grouping.